# How is UEFI different from a BIOS?

Tags: bios, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference in “Boot with BIOS” and “Boot with UEFI”](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)

I keep hearing about Windows8 now supporting UEFI. Can someone explain concisely what it means and **how it is different** from the traditional BIOS?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/332962/what-can-an-end-user-do-with-efi-or-uefi

Comment: Not a Windows 8 question :-)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UEFI is similar to an OS like BIOS but is not tied to any architecture. Also, UEFI is an interface and can be implemented on top of a BIOS.